# Show an image from json

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm not able to show an image that I load from a json file.
I'm parsing my json with JSONKit and everything works fine but I can't load an image in the `UIImageview`. I hope some of you can help me out there.

below my code I thought might be correct but it isn't.

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 115)];
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[detailView objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];

[self.view addSubview:image];
[image release];
```

Comment: what does this "[detailView objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]" contain?

Comment: are your image from remote server? or within  your project?

Comment: @janusfidel is from a remote server.
 it contains a string like below: 
  "thumbnail":"http://image.gamespotcdn.net/gamespot/images/2003/all/boxshots2/630498_214494.jpg",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code you posted

```
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[detailView objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];
```

will try to find the image on your bundle named the string stored in `[detailView objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]`

As you mentioned, your images are from remote server, you have to download the image from your remote server.

```
 UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 115)];
 image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[detailView objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]]];
[self.view addSubview:image];
[image release]
```

Answer (score 3):

i think in json u are getting url of image. display image from url using below code

```
 //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.2x0/pic/LC.jpg"];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[detailView objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];

 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,320.0f,  460.0f)];
 [subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]]; 
 [self.view addSubview:subview];
  [subview release];
```

Comment: Aaah thank you very much it worked very well.. i had a idea that it had something to do with the NSURL but i couldn't figure it out. Thank you very much.